# jQuery FullCalendar not rendering in Bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a working fullcalendar on my site, however, the actual calendar table doesn't show until you change the month/year or select "today".

I using the jquery Tabs and have the FullCalendar in the second tab, First tab is active. When I click on second tab then it shows only month/year, weekly, monthly and today. When I click on any of those button then calendar is showing up.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Would need to see your code to really help

Answer (score 8):

You must render fullcalendar when tab changed

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // TODO: check href of e.target to detect your tab
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
})
```